# NextJS: ReferenceError: window is not defined but no window is being called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to run

```
next dev
```

And I'm getting the following stack trace:

```
ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at __webpack_require__ (./.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
    at __webpack_require__ (./.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
    at eval (./src/component2.js:6:92)
    at (ssr)/./src/component2.js (./.next/server/app/unauthorized/page.js:547:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (./.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
    at eval (./src/component.js:14:87)
    at (ssr)/./src/component.js (./.next/server/app/unauthorized/page.js:525:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (./.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
    at eval (./app/layout.js:12:80)
    at (ssr)/./app/layout.js (./.next/server/app/unauthorized/page.js:338:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (./.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
```

sourceComponent.js:6

```
import Config from './Config.js';
```

and the contents of Config

```
const Config = {
    API_URL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL,
    //Other env vars are listed in a similar fashion
};

export default Config;
```

There are no calls to window in Config.js. Is there something else that could be calling window that's outside of my source?

Also the line number for component.js doesn't line up with any call. It's in the middle of an object declaration.

Is there anyway to find the window declaration? I've done a search through all of the source and have commented out calls to window. Those calls are all surrounded by the following check:

```
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
   //do work
}
```

Comment: Does your sourceComponent.js import any other (3rd-party) module? Some assumes a browser environment. Double check authentication libraries like keycloak-js etc..

Comment: I found a call to a library that my team developed. I haven't checked the contents but when I took the call out the problem disappeared. I'll see if I can figure out where in the source of this library is so that it can be resolved. Should I go ahead and answer the question?

Comment: The error indicates something about `/app/unauthorized/page.js`, have you taken a look at that file?

Comment: Add below code in useEffect.check the below code

React.useEffect(()=>{
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
   //do work
}
},[]);

Comment: @TaiweiTuan /app/unauthorized/page.js is a very simple React component. All that's in there are next/Image, material-ui/Typography and material-ui/paper. I'm not sure why that's showing up. 

I took a look at the library that appears to be causing the problem and the only thing that's in there is the following call to window: 
const ENV_VAR= window?.__env__?.ENV_VAR || process.env.ENV_VAR. 
If I move this code into my code it does not get the same error.

Comment: Thanks, but that still doesn't really help... the general rule of thumb is to make sure that `window` isn't being read during SSR. So, the solution might just be to move `const ENV_VAR= window?.__env__?.ENV_VAR || process.env.ENV_VAR` inside a `if (typeof window !== 'undefined')` block. Give it a try :)

Comment: I'll talk to the owners of the library and see if they can make this change. I don't think there's anything I can do on my side of the code.